# Creating a Developer Copy of another Sandbox

Tags: sandbox

What is the best approach to creating a Developer Copy sandbox of another sandbox ? I've read that you essentially need to deploy everything from one sandbox to the other. My question is how do I start the new Sandbox ? It sounds like I need a blank sandbox which I can start deploying all of my components into - but I don't know how to create that "blank" one.

Is this the right approach ? How do I create that "blank" sandbox ? Any kind of advice I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You create a sandbox from your production org. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not trying to make a sandbox which is a copy of Production. I want to create a sandbox which is a copy of ANOTHER sandbox.

Comment: And I don't think I'd be able to create another sandbox from Production and just deploying everything from the original sandbox into the new one because it will have all of the components which are in Production still left in there afterwards. At least that's what I think.

Answer (score 5):

To make a copy of a Sandbox, you would need to deploy configuration metadata from one instance to the other using the metadata API.  You can use either the Eclipse IDE, Ant, MavensMate or BrainEngine to move metadata from one instance to another. There is no copy function from one sandbox to another like there is when burning a sandbox from production.

Comment: Thank you @greenstork. So, I'm confused on how to do that. How would I do that in Eclipse ? I want to copy Sandbox A and make Sandbox B - so how I do take all of those components from Sandbox A and deploy them to a sandbox that hasn't been created yet ? How do I start on that ? I'm sorry if I've got stupid questions but I've never crated a new sandbox like this before.

Comment: Just create Sandbox B and then deploy from Sandbox A to Sandbox B

Comment: If you're asking about how to create a new sandbox, directions can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en

Comment: But if I do that then Sandbox B will start out as a copy of Production, and deploying from Sandbox A to B won't get rid of all the Production components which I do not want in Sandbox B, right ? I would end up with objects with fields that are in Prod which I do not necessarily want in this new Sandbox B along with other components from Prod which I do not want. Or am I missing something ... ? If I were to create a giant deploy package from Sandbox A to B would Eclipse highlight in red all of the components in Sandbox B which are not in the package and allow me to select them to delete them ?

Comment: Sandboxes are designed to be recent copies of production for the purpose of ultimately developing and deploying code to production. If you don't need metadata from production it begs the question of why use a sandbox at all, why not just a dev instance.

Comment: This sandbox is extremely different from Production. I am about to deploy a major release from this Sandbox into Production. I would like to have a backup copy of the sandbox to do any potential future development without doing it directly in that one.

Comment: So is there no way to begin a new Sandbox without it initially being a copy of Production ? If I am forced to start the new one as a copy of Production converting it to a copy of the already existing sandbox will be extremely tedious due to the inevitable errors which will come due to new fields or fields which will need to be deleted and so many other dependencies which will happen during the deployment. Deploying will inevetibly produce errors. It will be very difficult. Do you have any other approach ?

Comment: You understand correctly, there is no way to create a new sandbox without copying what is currently in production. The other approach I mentioned is to start a clean developer instance.

Comment: How can I start a clean developer instance ? The only thing I have ever done in the past is to create a new sandbox from Prod and then start developing in that.

Comment: i am using clients sandbox and so far lot of coding, configurations has been done in it.

Now i need the same replica of client's sandbox in my free dev org so that i can use it for my future reference to see what i did and also helping myself for my interview preparations by giving a glance of the working model in my free dev org... How can i achieve this?

i have been using Eclipse for the development in sandbox. Little bit confused of choosing appropriate tags..

Comment: In Eclipse for your client project, edit the project to add all metadata. Then select it all from the sidebar, right click on the selection > Force.com menu and then Deploy to Server

Comment: If I were to go the route of Eclipse... how is this impacted by needing (in my example) Financial Force and Rootstock installed?   Our main/Full Sandbox has those installed (and the hundreds of objects, apex snippets, visualforce, etc) while Production (yet) does not.    Ugh.   Thanks.