# How do you copy metadata from sandbox to sandbox?

Tags: sandbox

What is the process if doing COPY of SANDBOX A to SANDBOX B in new org?
What are the key steps to do and key documentation / data? What are key milestones in the process?

What is the role of API, API signing tool, CDN?
What are the Pros/ Cons of CDN?

Are the any templates or best practices?

Comment: Juraj, that's a combination of questions that is hard to answer without knowing what specifically is not clear to you. To deploy between sandboxes of different orgs you need to use packages or the metadata API.

Comment: I'll use ANT tool to make a copy to target sandbox.  I understand I need clear package to be deployed, target system and source system. I'm asking what steps I need to do to do full deployment process ( i.e. detail about deployment, test, etc. ). Additionally I want to make some additional changes, test again (I understand internal test and UAT/regression test are included) and then deploy to product. I want to know it to be able to manage the team of developers to get the thing done (so I'm not developer)

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/creating-a-developer-copy-of-another-sandbox

Comment: yes...deleted the duplicate to follow the discussion here - i think it it separate topic

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find the answers to your questions in the [Development Lifecycle Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/). There's also a Trailhead module called [Application Lifecycle Managment](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/alm_deployment) that covers similar material which should be helpful to you as well.

**Edit**

CDN stands for [Content Delivery Network](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_caching.htm&language=en_US). It's basically a caching option to help improve page load times and site performance, as well as your org avoid reaching bandwidth or service request time limits through the use of the `<apex:page cache="true" expires="900">` setting (values are example of page that expires in 15 min). This setting only applies to Force.com Sites since SSL sessions and pages requested after authentication are not cached.

API stands for [Application Programming Interface](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm) which allows secure programmatic access to your Salesforce org's information; both outbound and inbound to connect with other organizations. The [Salesforce1 Platform API Services Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/salesforce1_platform_intro.htm) provides a description of all of the API's and some example integration use cases. You may also find [Integration Patterns and Practices](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/integration_patterns_and_practices.pdf) useful as well.

The answers to your Sandbox testing questions are greatly dependent on the size of your organization, it's resources and the type of changes you're making. Again, I highly recommend the Trailhead module I've referred you to above along with the Development Lifecycle Guide. I don't believe there's a "One size fit's all answer to your question". I suggest you review the material, then come back and ask questions that are specific to your situation and scenario.

Comment: what about API? is it interface for communication (i.e. web service?)? I want to understand What is it for? & Technical background.

Comment: the same about the CDN? why to use it and what is the added value? It's kind of storage I understand => for what purpose is it used?

Comment: and one process question: If I deploy the Sandbox A to Sandbox B, the next steps are tests of functionality, Regression tests with customer? What should I be careful about, i.e. what are must ToDo's?

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I believe it addresses all of your questions.